# Select value from based on interval Time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

**persona_df**

```
time                       uid
11/21/2020  3:37:00 PM     1
11/21/2020  5:33:00 PM     1
11/21/2020  6:58:00 PM     2
11/21/2020  3:53:00 PM     2
11/21/2020  6:02:00 PM     3
11/21/2020  6:25:00 PM     3
```

time: datetime64

id: object

**show_df**

```
start                       end                       artist_name
11/21/2020  2:50:00 PM     11/21/2020  4:00:00 PM      A
11/21/2020  4:00:00 PM     11/21/2020  5:10:00 PM      B
11/21/2020  5:10:00 PM     11/21/2020  6:20:00 PM      C
11/21/2020  6:20:00 PM     11/21/2020  7:30:00 PM      D
```

start: datetime64

end: datetime64

artist: object

**Expected output**

```
uid   artist_name
1     A
1     C
2     C
2     A
3     C
3     D
```

I want to select an **artist_name** in conditions of showtime and map to **uid**

describe:
uid = 1 live in 3:37:00 PM And 5:33:00 PM
that artist A  show on 2:50:00 PM  to 4:00:00 PM
and  artist:B  show on 4:00:00 PM  to 5:10:00 PM

Comment: Cannot understand your problem clearly, please elaborate more or otherwise everyone will downvote it.

Comment: I not sure why not clearly, I want to map uid and artist by showtime